# (python) docstring is causing indentation error

Tags: python, indentation

```
def getText(nodelist):
    """Extracts the text between XML tags

    I took this directly from http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html.
    For example, if I have a tag <Tag>525</Tag> this method returns me '525'
    """
    rc = ""
    for node in nodelist:
        if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
            rc = rc + node.data
    return rc
```

Gives me `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

```
def getText(nodelist):
    rc = ""
    for node in nodelist:
        if node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE:
            rc = rc + node.data
    return rc
```

Does not. All I am doing is deleting the docstring comment. What is going on?

Comment: `return ''.join(n.data for n in nodelist if n.nodeType == n.TEXT_NODE)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your docstring starts with tabs.  Make your code only use spaces for indentation (or only tabs), including the indentation for the docstrings.

Comment: Similar issue: Empty lines must have same amounts of leading whitespace as surrounding code.

Comment: I understand that a lot of people have strong opinion against Python but it is very beginner-friendly language still! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are not mixing spaces and tabs for your indentation